# KendoUI combobox on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, kendo-ui, focus

```
$("#" + id).tie("focus", function () {
    alert();
});
```

I am trying to get a Kendo combobox to do something when given focus. I cannot seem to be able to get the focus event though, I replaced the actual contents with an alert to test, but cannot get the alert to be present. What do I need to tie the focus to?

Comment: Try on instead of tie, otherwise your code should work

Comment: @Mark just tried that, did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two questions to keep in mind:

1. Kendo UI wraps your input element with some additional HTML that is used to maintain visual compatibility (among others) between browsers. So when you actually say `$("#" + id)` you are selecting a hidden `input` element.
2. Kendo UI sometimes creates elements not when you think but a little later (example, when you get data from a server might happen that the HTML is not generated until you the data is received).

So, you should use:

```
$("#" + id).data("kendoComboBox").input.on("focus", function () {
    console.log("here");
});
```

Where I use `$("#" + id).data("kendoComboBox").input` for actually accessing the `input` element that is being used by the user. Documentation on `input` [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#fields-input)

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qgrjsak4/3/